# Catkin_make looking in wrong directory for header files

Tags: catkin-make, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ros kinetic ubuntu 16.04 on intel NUC. I put g2ofork in my workspaces src thinking it was a catkin package but I later found out it was not. I moved it outside my WS and attempted to use rgbslam package which requires the g2o libraries. When I catkin_make the workspace it fails because it is still looking in my workspace/src/g2ofork directory. I know this because catkin_make has some warning type messages

```
- - looking for PCL_COMMON
- - looking for PCL_OCTREE
- - looking for PCL_IO
- - Searching for g2o ...
- - found g2o headers in: /home/astrobotics/ros_code/src/g2ofork
- - found libg2o: /home/astrobotics/ros_code/src/g2ofork/lib/ and so on...
```

I know right now all the packages and g2o fork are in the correct places because when I use the install script provided by rgbdslam it sets everything up as I have mine now. The only thing is it creates its own workspace and I want to use it in the one I have been using for some time.

Is there any way to like reset the workspace before building it again?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287036/catkin_make-looking-in-wrong-directory-for-header-files/) by [skynet](https://answers.ros.org/users/33478/skynet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2018-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try deleting the `build` and `install` directories from the root of the workspace?

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skynet](https://answers.ros.org/users/33478/skynet/) on 2018-03-30**:
I replaced the build with a build file from a different workspace that is able to compile that has the same configuration that I want (home/astro/test/workspace/src/rgbdslam and /home/astrobotics/test/g2ofork) and it works. Only thing is it is obviously using the g2o fork from the test workspace.

**Comment by [skynet](https://answers.ros.org/users/33478/skynet/) on 2018-03-30**:
when I delete the build and re compile i get the error

```
-- Searching for g2o ...
CMake Error at rgbdslam/cmake-modules/FindG2O.cmake:78 (message):
  Could not find libg2o!
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  rgbdslam/CMakeLists.txt:91 (find_package)
```

**Comment by [skynet](https://answers.ros.org/users/33478/skynet/) on 2018-03-30**:
deleting the old build file worked because it was holding the wrong directories to g2o. My CMakeCache.txt had the old directories to the g2o library so I manually replaced them with the correct ones.